# List of public API unavailable for Apple App Extensions

Tags: swift, ios10, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions

iOS App extensions are not allowed to use all available public Apple API.

This [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) lists some restrictions. For instance:

> Because of its focused role in the system, an app extension is ineligible to participate in certain activities. An app extension cannot: ... Access the camera or microphone on an iOS device...

But in [WWDC 2016 iMesages Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/204/) is mentioned that iMessage apps, in contrast to other extension types, are allowed to access the camera though.

**Conclusion:**

- iOS App extensions are not allowed to use all available public Apple API
- different kind of app extensions have a different set of restrictions

**Problem:**

I can not find valid information regarding restrictions for each kind of extension (iMessage Extension, Photo Extansion...).

**Question:**

Is there a source of trustworthy information, listing the different restrictions for differnet extension types?